# If $n$ is a prime power, is there an isomorphism between $Z_n [x] /f_1$ and $Z_n [x] /f_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $n =p^r$ is not prime and $Z_n$ is a ring.

Consider two irreducible polynomial $f_1$ and $f_2$ of degree $d$ over $Z_n$.

Can we find an isomorphism between $Z_n [x] /f_1$ and $Z_n [x] /f_2$ ??

I think that is impossible, However that is only feel.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $Z_n$ supposed to denote the ring of integers modulo $n$?

Comment: That's right. I think zero divisor has a problem, but I don't know

Comment: Oh really? Then this problem is not well-defined. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is not a prime, then the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain, so $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[x]$ is not either. Unfortunately, it's unclear what "irreducible element" means in a ring that is not an integral domain - [look on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element).

However, perhaps an example such as the following would still be satisfactory to you: let $n=4$, and let $f_1=1+x$ and $f_2=1+3x$. Then
$$(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[x]/(f_1)\cong\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\cong(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[x]/(f_2)$$

Comment: Thank you :) I know new one.